# Public .NET Website. Detect if a user is coming from inside our company vs the public?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I'm create an internet site, and there are a few pages that I would like to display differently if the user is accessing the site from inside our firewall (employees accessing the site at work from their work computers) vs someone accessing the site from home ... the general public.  Is there a way to determine if the user is inside our network or a public user? This in an ASP.NET website with a vb.net code behind.

Comment: Does the user have to login to use the site?

Comment: NO.  The site doesn't have a login.

Answer (score 3):

Easy: Look for the IP address of the requester and compare to your network.

Other: Another solution is to have two virtual directories. One with anonymous access and one using windows authentication with the differentiation being the port number. You can then simply provide different/extended content to the authenticated user.